# Transfer diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to create a transfer diagram for a model that I am working on. However, I am new to drawing diagrams on LaTeX. Could someone kindly suggest how to draw the following figure on LaTeX?

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) "Do it for me" questions are not well received on this website, especially since there are a lot of examples of what you are trying to do already present. Please provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/184389) of what you have tried so far and what precise point you are struggling with.

Comment: I would suggest you start by looking at [TikZ](http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/CTAN/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) and [tikzcd](https://mirrors.chevalier.io/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-cd/tikz-cd-doc.pdf) packages to see how your drawing can be achieved.

Comment: @KersouMan Thanks a lot for the feedback; will do.

Comment: @KersouMan thanks for the links to the packages documentations.

Comment: My guess is that the downvotes have been triggered especially by the sentence "It will save me very long time if ..". I'd suggest to edit the question to rephrase this sentence. Everyone's time is valuable.

Comment: Thanks @AlessandroCuttin for the important suggestion and the valued help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[%
            node distance = 17mm,
            state/.style = {%
                rectangle,
                        draw = black,
                   inner sep = 0pt,
                minimum size = 7mm,
                thick,
            },
            beta/.style = {%
            node distance = 2mm,
                inner sep = 1pt,
            },
            auto,
        ]
        \node (a1) [state] {$A_1$};
        \node (a2) [right=of a1,state] {$A_2$};
        \node (a5) [right=of a2,state] {$A_5$};
        \node (a6) [right=of a5,state] {$A_6$};
        \node (a3) [above=of a2,state] {$A_3$};
        \node (a4) [below=of a2,state] {$A_4$};
        \node (a8) [above right=of a6,state] {$A_8$};
        \node (a7) [below right=of a6,state] {$A_7$};

        \draw [->] (a1) to node {$\alpha_2$} (a2);
        \draw [->] (a3) to node {$\alpha_1$} (a2);
        \draw [->] (a2) to node {$\alpha_2$} (a4);
        \draw [->] (a2) to node {$\alpha_3$} (a5);
        \draw [->,swap] (a4) to node {$\alpha_4$} (a5);
        \draw [->] (a5) to node {$\alpha_5$} (a6);
        \draw [->] (a6) to node {$\alpha_6$} (a8);
        \draw [->] (a6) to node {$\alpha_7$} (a7);

        \node (b1) [beta,left=of a3] {$\beta_1$};
        \node (b2) [beta,right=of a3] {$\beta_2$};
        \node (b4) [beta,below=of a1] {$\beta_4$};
        \node (b5) [beta,below right=of a2] {$\beta_5$};
        \node (b7) [beta,below=of a5] {$\beta_7$};
        \node (b8) [beta,below=of a6] {$\beta_8$};
        \node (b9) [beta,below=of a8] {$\beta_9$};
        \node (b10) [beta,below=of a7] {$\beta_{10}$};

        \draw [->] (a1) -- (b4);
        \draw [->] (b1) -- (a3);
        \draw [->] (a3) -- (b2);
        \draw [->] (a2) -- (b5);
        \draw [->] (a5) -- (b7);
        \draw [->] (a6) -- (b8);
        \draw [->] (a8) -- (b9);
        \draw [->] (a7) -- (b10);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Sir for your kind assistance